# Is it possible to configure Chrome 'Make a call' popover from my web application?

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

For example, in some place of my web app I have clickable a phone number:

```
<a href="tel:+1234567890"> +1234567890 </a>
```

This phone number occur 'Make a call' popover in Chrome. But some screen readers read the info in this popover a few times, but shouldn't. For example result from JAWS reader:

[image: JAWS screen reader read 'make a call from' popover twice]

So, is it possible to configure this popover from my web app?

---

[Example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/href-tel-popover-a11y-issue?file=index.html)

---

UPD: 'Make a call' popover: [image]

Comment: looks like it is skype that has the issue, the problem is I don't have it installed. Could you inspect the element and see if / what elements, WAI-ARIA etc. it adds. I doubt there is much you can do with this as your HTML is valid and I would imagine anything we do to try and improve the experience for Skype users will only make things worse for everyone else.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie looks like I can't inspect this element and can apply changes just in Chrome settings

Comment: Then I would imagine there isn't much you can do unfortunately. I could be wrong but it is my gut reaction that nothing we do will persuade the skype plugin to behave better. The only thing I can think is to actually remove the anchor wrapping it and try it - I would guess the duplication is from the fact it finds the phone number as text and as a `href`. If that is the case then you just have the choice to make of whether to make it a hyperlink and put up with poor Skype behaviour or make it plain text and reduce functionality (I would obviously say leave it as it is and ignore Skype!)