# JAWS reads Modal Dialog content twice

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, wcag

My Modal Dialog has interactive and non-interactive content (screenshot 1). I'm expecting that the screen reader will read all content before the first focusable item and this focused item as well. But instead of that JAWS reads all content twice and then the focused item as well (screenshot 2).

Is there any way how to obligate the screen reader to read all content before the first focusable item and this focused item as well?

---

[Demo here (last example).](https://deploy-preview-5493--fundamental-ngx.netlify.app/#/core/quick-view#in-dialog)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this not the same issue that I described in your last question where Skype is interfering? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67790921/is-it-possible-to-configure-chrome-make-a-call-popover-from-my-web-application, have you tried the above in a browser without Skype installed?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie no, it's not related to the previous question. I've tried on the clear Windows machine without Skype.

Comment: The modal is hidden from view but is still in the document flow so make sure before it's visible it has a tabindex="-1" to take it out of the AOM/Accessibility flow. Then it's only read when it launches (it has to then receive focus via js and tabindex="0".

Comment: @NathanielFlick my dialog appears to the document by JS just after the button click.